# How to add image on hover in <li>::after

Tags: html, css

I want a structure like this on `<li>` hover (Blue down arrow on **center** of every li)

[image]

But I'm unable to make this because i thought i will use this blue image as  pseudo elements `::after` but i have added ":" in between two `<li>`.

This is my html code :

```
<div class="quick-links col-md-12">
<p class="left" style="font-weight:600;font-family:calibri;">Go quickly 
to</p>
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="color:#2ca5fa;padding:0px 3px 0px 12px;"></i>
<ul class="quick-ul">
            <li><a href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bath Towels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LED Bulbs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Washing Machines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Headphones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code :

```
.quick-links {

    height: 52px;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 20px;
display: inline-table;
padding-top: 13px;
border-top: 4px solid #0096ff;
}

.left {

float: left;
}

.quick-ul {

float: right;
display: inline-flex;
}

.quick-ul li {

font-family: calibri;
padding-right: 39px;
position: relative;
margin-left: -34px;
font-size: 15px;
}

.quick-ul li>a { 
color: black;
}

.quick-ul li>a:hover {
color: #0096ff; 
}

.quick-ul li::after {

content: ":";
color: black;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
font-weight: 100 !important;

}

.quick-ul li:nth-last-child(1)::after{
content: ""; 
}
```

Any Kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this rule

```
.quick-ul li>a:hover::after
  content: "\25bc";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) scaleX(2);
  color: #0096ff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

It will add a filled arrow character using the pseudo `::after`, that is easily colored and sized as any other character. The `translate` moves it into place and the `scaleX` makes it a little wider.

Stack snippet

```css
.quick-links {
  height: 52px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-table;
  border-top: 4px solid #0096ff;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.quick-ul {
  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;                 /*  added property  */
}

.quick-ul li {
  font-family: calibri;
  padding-right: 39px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -34px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.quick-ul li>a {
  color: black;
}

.quick-ul li>a:hover {
  position: relative;               /*  added property  */
  color: #0096ff;
}

.quick-ul li>a:hover::after {       /*  added rule  */
  content: "\25bc";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) scaleX(2);
  color: #0096ff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.quick-ul li::after {
  content: ":";
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}

.quick-ul li:nth-last-child(1)::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-links col-md-12">
  <p class="left" style="font-weight:600;font-family:calibri;">Go quickly to
  </p>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="color:#2ca5fa;padding:0px 3px 0px 12px;"></i>
  <ul class="quick-ul">
      <li><a href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bath Towels</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LED Bulbs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you:

```css
.quick-links {
height: 52px;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 20px;
border-top: 4px solid #0096ff;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px !important;
}

.left {

float: left;
}

.quick-ul {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.quick-ul li {
position: relative;
font-family: Arial;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 15px;
margin: 0px 1px; 
display: inline;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.quick-ul li:not(:last-child)::before {
 content: ":";
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 right: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
}

.quick-ul li>a { 

display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: blue;
padding: 12px 18px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box; 
position: relative;
}

.quick-ul li>a:hover {
color: #0096ff; 
}

.quick-ul li > a::after {
display: block;
content: "";
color: blue;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
font-weight: 100 !important;
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
margin-top: -5px;
font-size: 18px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px; left: 50%;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.quick-ul li>a:hover::after {content: '\25B6'}
```

```html
<div class="quick-links col-md-12">
<ul class="quick-ul">
 <li><a href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: updating my answer according to your need..!

Comment: Its not working its replacing ":" with your given content.

Comment: made this code only for icon on hover you need to modify it according to your proper need...!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.quick-links {
  height: 52px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-table;
  padding-top: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #0096ff;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.quick-ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.quick-ul li {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.quick-ul li>a {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.quick-ul li>a:hover {
  color: #0096ff;
}

.quick-ul li::after {
  content: ":";
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}

.quick-ul li:nth-last-child(1)::after {
  content: "";
}


/* additional styles */

.quick-ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-top: 10px solid #0096ff;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease 0.15s;
}

.quick-ul li:hover a::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-links col-md-12">
  <p class="left" style="font-weight:600;font-family:calibri;">Go quickly to
  </p>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="color:#2ca5fa;padding:0px 3px 0px 12px;"></i>
  <ul class="quick-ul">
    <li><a href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bath Towels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LED Bulbs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```